# VB.NET based MVC Web Application - build errors after no code change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to add my solution to this problem, but there must be other ways around it.

I'm building an MVC VB.NET based web app. Sometimes I won't even change the (previously working) code, and I'll try debugging using MSVS2010 -  then I'll get the old "Build Errors" pop up.
This is annoying...

If anyone has a better solution than mine I'd be interested to know - I've heard about filters and stuff like that, maybe that's the route to go down... but for now, I'll post my very simple solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I discovered is simple, and I'm posting this because a lot of people might go down the same road that I did, and frantically Google reasons why previously working code now has build errors - a question I still don't know the answer to...
However, here's a simple workaround:

CLEAN!!!!
It's real easy, in MSVS2010, go to the "Build" dropdown from the toolbar, then press "Clean Solution".
Not sure why, but for some reason, this seems to work!